# Showing posts from 2 categories only on category.php

Tags: categories, get-posts

got myself in a bit of a pickle.
I want to display posts on category.php from the categories 'latest news' and 'custom models' only. The other category, 'press releases' is shown in a separate column.

I've the following code - hashed together from misc articles I've read - but it's showing ALL the posts rather than just my 2 chosen categories.

Perhaps the easiest way would be to show all posts apart from 'press releases'...

Can anyone help?

```
  <div id="rightColumn">
    <h1>
      <?php single_cat_title() ?>
    </h1>
    <?php $posts = get_posts('category=Latest News,Custom Models'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
    <div class="newsListing">
      <div class="imageContainer"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php
// Must be inside a loop.

if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail('size-2');
}
else {
    echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/shared/placeholder.jpg" />';
}
?>
        </a></div>
      <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a></h2>
      <h3>
        <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
      </h3>
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
      <p class="readMore"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a></p>
      <div class="clearBoth"></div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
    <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
      <p class="floatRight">
        <?php posts_nav_link('','&lt; Recent entries','Older entries &gt;'); ?>
      </p>
      <div class="clearBoth"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `get_posts` accepts comma separated categories' ids or slugs, not names. As it makes use of `WP_Query`, see [Category Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters).

Comment: So code will change to this... <?php $posts = get_posts('category_name=latest-news,custom-models'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>

Comment: Yes, that's right.